SciFi book written before 1997: includes body swapping by suicide & making deposits by expressing extreme joy
The main character finds they are getting more and more unsettled in a society where life is about extreme feelings of excitement or joy. There are ads showing up everywhere to buy things. There are "deposit" machines  where individuals express extreme joy or excitement into them. They can also switch into new bodies, the new bodies being broadcasted in the sky so people still know who they are. The main character decides to escape out of the community to the farthest outpost and stays in their body. They succeed and join a group of people. I've been looking for the name of this book for years having read it in 1997. I believe it was an older book at that time.

This sounds like Don't Bite the Sun by Tanith Lee, though you may have read the book Biting the Sun that collects Don't Bite the Sun and it's sequel Drinking Sapphire Wine into a single volume.

Don't Bite the Sun is a 1976 science fiction novel by Tanith Lee set in a utopian world which the main character comes to reject. The main character and her friends are wild, crazy "Jang" teenagers whose lifestyle is full of reckless behaviour, promiscuous sex, repeated suicide (upon dying, they are reborn), and a constant search for thrills. Over the course of the story, the nameless narrator fails to relate to her seven Jang friends but finds herself, feels emotion, and learns love.

It starts with an example of the body switching:

My friend Hergal had killed himself again. This was the fortieth time he had crashed his bird-plane on to the Zeefahr Monument and had to have a new body made.

and broadcast of the new body is called a flash. For example when the protagonist changes her body we read:

Well, I mean, Yd had it flashed all over the city that my new body was pale and slim, with knee-length silver hair and antennae.

The part about founding a new settlement outside the city happens in the sequel, which is why I suspect you might have read Biting the Sun.
If I am allowed an editorial comment it's that Lee is one of those authors  who seem to be largely forgotten these days but who were influential in their day and are worth rediscovering. Her books are not always easy to read but are (mostly) worth the effort. She even wrote two episodes of Blake's Seven! There is an obituary of her on the Guardian web site that has a nice discussion of her legacy.

That's it!!! Thank you so much. It's been bugging me for a long time.

@Oneeyedsage Please click on the tick symbol next to my answer as that marks it as accepted. Thanks :-)

Her obit really delved in and was an enjoyable read of her life's work. Thanks again for sharing your answer. It was an "aha!" moment to be sure!
